# python numpy - is there a faster way to convolve?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have a numpy array that is very large (1 million integers). I'm using np.convolve  in order to find the "densest" area of that array. By "desnsest" area I mean the window of a fixed length that has the the highest numbers when the window is summed. Let me show you in code:

```
import numpy as np

example = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0])
window_size = 10
density = np.convolve(example, np.ones([window_size]), mode='valid')
print(density) 
# [7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0]
```

I can then use `np.argmax(density)` to get the starting index of the highest density area `3`.

Anyway, with this example it runs fast. but when convolving over million element array and with a window size of 10,000 it takes 2 seconds to complete. if I choose a windows_size of 500,000 it takes 3 minutes to complete.

Is there a better way to sum over the array with a certain window size to speed this up? If I converted this into a pandas series instead could I perhaps use something there?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).  It has the option to compute the convolution using the fast Fourier transform (FFT), which should be much faster for the array sizes that you mentioned.

Using an array `example` with length 1000000 and convolving it with an array of length `10000`, `np.convolve` took about 1.45 seconds on my computer, and `scipy.signal.convolve` took 22.7 milliseconds.

Comment: If there is a faster implementation why doesn't numpy take advantage of it (by default)? Is there a tradeoff when using FFT?

Answer (score 2):

```
cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(example, 0, 0))

density2 = cumsum[window_size:]-cumsum[:-window_size]

np.all(density2 == density)

True
```

(remove insertion if you can live without the first value...)

Answer (score 1):

**This** is how you can use the built-in NumPy real FFT functions to convolve in 1 dimension:

```
import numpy, numpy.fft.fftpack_lite

def fftpack_lite_rfftb(buf, s):
    n = len(buf)
    m = (n - 1) * 2
    temp = numpy.empty(m, buf.dtype)
    numpy.divide(buf, m, temp[:n])
    temp[n:m] = 0
    return numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.rfftb(temp[:m], s)

def fftconvolve(x, y):
    xn = x.shape[-1]
    yn = y.shape[-1]
    cn = xn + yn - (xn + yn > 0)
    m = 1 << cn.bit_length()
    s = numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.rffti(m)  # Initialization; can be factored out for performance
    xpad = numpy.pad(x, [(0, 0)] * (len(x.shape) - 1) + [(0, m - xn)], 'constant')
    a = numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.rfftf(xpad, s)  # Forward transform
    ypad = numpy.pad(y, [(0, 0)] * (len(y.shape) - 1) + [(0, m - yn)], 'constant')
    b = numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.rfftf(ypad, s)  # Forward transform
    numpy.multiply(a, b, b)  # Spectral multiplication
    c = fftpack_lite_rfftb(b, s)  # Backward transform
    return c[:cn]

# Verify convolution is correct
assert (lambda a, b: numpy.allclose(fftconvolve(a, b), numpy.convolve(a, b)))(numpy.random.randn(numpy.random.randint(1, 32)), numpy.random.randn(numpy.random.randint(1, 32)))
```

Bear in mind that this padding is inefficient for convolution of vectors with significantly different sizes (> 100%); you'll want to use a linear combination technique like overlap-add to do smaller convolution.

Comment: What numpy version did you use? Mine doesn't find numpy.fft.fftpack_lite or simply fftpack